# Only username, password and email fields are being populated

Tags: php, mysqli

I am running following query to register a new user. However, only username, password and email address fields are being inserted into the database.
I have checked, the spellings exactly match with the ones I have in database.
Not sure where is the issue.
I have commented out some of the code in order to figure out the issue.Here is the complete code:

```html
<?php

/* Main page with two forms: sign up and log in */
require 'db_connection.php';
session_start();

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Sign-Up Form: <?php include 'css/css.html'; ?></title>

</head>

<?php





/* form.php */
//session_start();
$_SESSION['message'] = '<div class="alert alert-error"><?= $_SESSION[\'message\'] ?></div>';
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'customer.accounts');

/*if (isset($_POST['btn-submit']))
    $first_name = ($_POST['first_name']);
    $last_name = ($_POST['last_name']);
    $username = ($_POST['username']);
    $DeliveryAddress= ($_POST['DeliveryAddress']);
    $CreditCardNo= ($_POST['CreditCardNo']);   */


if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
//check if two passwords match
  //  if ($_POST['password'] == $_POST['password']) {

        //define other variables with submitted values from $_POST,

        $username = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
        $email = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
        $first_name = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['first_name']);
        $last_name = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['last_name']);
        $password = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
        $DeliveryAddress = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['DeliveryAddress']);
        $CreditCardNo = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['CreditCardNo']);


        //md5 hash password for security
        $password = md5($_POST['password']);
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;



    if(!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/',$first_name))   //validate firstname
    {
        $nameErr="Name can only contain alphabets";
        $execute=false;
    }
    if(!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/',$last_name))   //validate lastname
    {
        $nameErr="Name can only contain alphabets";
        $execute=false;
    }
    if(!preg_match('/^[0-9]*$/',$ContactNo))    //validate phone
    {
        $phoneErr="Mobile Number can only contain digits";
        $execute=false;
    }
    if(strlen($ContactNo)<10)
    {
        $phoneErr="<br/>Mobile number is too short";
        $execute=false;
    }

    if(strlen($CreditCardNo)<16)                                 //validate card details
    {
        $phoneErr="<br/>Credit Card Number is too short";
        $execute=false;
    }
    if($execute!=false)


        //Bind and insert user data into database
        $sql = "INSERT INTO useraccounts (first_name,last_name,username, email, password,DeliveryAddress,CreditCardNo) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        $stmt->bind_param('ssssssi', $first_name, $last_name, $username,$email,$password,$DeliveryAddress,$CreditCardNo);
        $username= $_SESSION('username');
        $stmt->execute();



        //check if mysql query is successful, then register the user.
        if ($stmt === true) {
            $_SESSION['message'] = "Registration successful!"
                . "Added $username to the database!";
            //redirect the user to welcome.php if the registration is successful
            header("location: welcome.php");

        } else {
            $_SESSION['message'] = 'User could not be added to the database!';
        }

        $mysqli->close();

    //else {
     //   $_SESSION['message'] = 'Two passwords do not match!';



//if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")


}

function test_input($data){
    $data=trim($data);
    $data=htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}
//Registration Form

?>
<link href="//db.onlinewebfonts.com/c/a4e256ed67403c6ad5d43937ed48a77b?family=Core+Sans+N+W01+35+Light" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="form.css" type="text/css">
<div class="body-content">
    <div class="module">
        <h1>Create an Account </h1>


        <form class="form" action="form.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off">

            <div class="alert alert-error"> <?= $_SESSION['message'] ?></div>
            <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="first_name" required />
            <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="last_name" required />

            <input type="text" placeholder="User Name" name="username" required />
            <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" required />
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" autocomplete="new-password" required />
            <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" name="confirmpassword" autocomplete="new-password" required />
            <input type="text" placeholder="Delivery Address" name="DeliveryAddress" autocomplete="DeliveryAddress" required />
            <input type="text" placeholder="Payment Details" name="CreditCardNo" autocomplete="CreditCardNo" required />

            <input type="submit" value="Register" name="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" />

        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: storing credit card numbers huh? I hope you know what you're doing

Comment: btw, `$_SESSION` isn't a function, it's a (superglobal) array.

Comment: Where is the php with the form validation, and where is the html form.  If you can post that it would help

Comment: Please let me know the name of the store that this is for so that I make sure to never use it.

Comment: Important note - you are using `prepare()/bind_param()/execute()` which means you should _not_ be calling `real_escape_string()` on these values. Doing so double-escapes them, storing incorrect values in your table.

Comment: Another significant logic issue (though wouldn't prevent the INSERT  -you are comparing `$_POST['password']` to _itself_ rather than to `$_POST['confirmpassword']`

Comment: You never did `$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);`

Comment: ^^ And therefore the fact that you are seeing _anything_ inserted at all means the code you are actually running is not the code you have posted here. There's no way this code could result in any partial or complete insert.

Comment: the edit is SO much different than the original; it should never have happened, IMHO and is a complete mess.

Answer (score -2):

Ivar, I believe you may be complicating the situation by using bound parameters.  This adds a level of indirection for an otherwise simple query. For standard queries, I would use parameter markers, for example (with debugging added):

```
// Your SQL with parameter markers to create a prepared statment
$stmt = $pdo->prepare(
    "INSERT INTO useraccounts (first_name, last_name, username, email, 
                               password, DeliveryAddress, CreditCardNo) 
          VALUES (:first_name, :last_name, :username, :email, 
                  :password, :DeliveryAddress, :CreditCardNo)";

// All parameters markers must be satisfied in this array
$params = [
    ':first_name'      => $first_name,
    ':last_name'       => $last_name,
    ':username'        => $username,
    ':email'           => $email,
    ':password'        => $password,
    ':DeliveryAddress' => $DeliveryAddress,
    ':CreditCardNo'    => $CreditCardNo
];

// Export the array to a file, or simply using print_r 
file_put_contents('/tmp/params.txt', var_export($params, true));

// Execute the PDO statement
$stmt->execute($params);
```

The exported file is only there to assist with finding the source of your original issue of the unset parameters.  If they are set in the array, they should be set via your query as well.  If the SQL is invalid, it will fail in the prepare call.  If the parameter list is incorrect, it will fail in the execute call.

Comment: He's using mysqli, not PDO.

Comment: You are implicitly suggesting the OP switch entirely from MySQLi (which doesn't support named params) to PDO. There could be dozens of reasons why that isn't practical.

Comment: Yes, good point.  So many reasons to go with PDO, but I can see why that may not work for all.

Comment: And even if there are good reasons to switch to PDO, this doesn't explain why his code doesn't work. Changing APIs is not a magic bullet.

Comment: Exporting the parameter list can assist with that, which is shown in the code.